# Web config transformation don't create config files when I deploy in different environment

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

I've added web config transformation in my project. When I deploy the project using Octopus deployment it doesn't create web.config file. I've already changed properties to do not copy on for all files and build action = content. Do you think Is it because of files naming convention. I've got below naming convention for my files.

```
Web.Test.comInternal.config
Web.Test.WebFarm.config
Web.Dev.comInternal.config
Web.Dev.WebFarm.config
Web.Production.comInternal.config
Web.Production.WebFarm.config
```

Do you think the above naming convention could cause this issue.

Comment: okay that's fixed now. The main web.config file wasn't set to build action=content.

Comment: When I deploy it on octopus it works fine but it copies settings from Web.Release.config file instead of Web.Test.comInternal.config. Any clue?

Comment: I've fixed it finally. In your octopus -> process add this line in Additional transforms 
Web.#{Octopus.Environment.Name}.BodenInternal.config =>web.config 
and for webfarm add this one 
Web.#{Octopus.Environment.Name}.webfarm.config =>web.config